# Trouble understanding error handling with monads

Tags: haskell, monads, monadplus

I'm trying to build a function which returns me the single element from a list. The list is part of a `Maybe (Int,[Int])` tupel.

If the list contains no elements, I want to return an error.
If the list contains exactly 1 element, I want to return that element as a Monad.
If the list contains more than 1 element, I want to return an error.

I'm a bit lost and cannot see how to make this rather simple thing work.
Here is what I have so far:

```
import Control.Monad

test1 = Just (1,[2,3]) :: Maybe (Int,[Int])
test2 = Just (2,[1]) :: Maybe (Int,[Int])
test3 = Just (3,[]) :: Maybe (Int,[Int])

getValue :: Maybe Bool -> Bool
getValue (Just x) = x
getValue Nothing = False

singleElemOnly :: (MonadPlus m) => [a] -> m a
singleElemOnly x = let result = test2
                       value = fmap fst result
                       isEmpty = fmap null (fmap snd result)
                   in if (getValue isEmpty) then value else mzero
```

Unfortunately the error messages I am getting when trying to compile this are of absolutely no use to me as a beginner..

```
Playground.hs:15:50:
    Could not deduce (a ~ Int)
    from the context (MonadPlus m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 singleElemOnly :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a
      at Playground.hs:11:19-45
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for singleElemOnly :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a
          at Playground.hs:11:19
    Expected type: m a
      Actual type: Maybe Int
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: [a]
        (bound at Playground.hs:12:16)
      singleElemOnly :: [a] -> m a
        (bound at Playground.hs:12:1)
    In the expression: value
    In the expression: if (getValue isEmpty) then value else mzero

Playground.hs:15:50:
    Could not deduce (m ~ Maybe)
    from the context (MonadPlus m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 singleElemOnly :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a
      at Playground.hs:11:19-45
      `m' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for singleElemOnly :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a
          at Playground.hs:11:19
    Expected type: m a
      Actual type: Maybe Int
    Relevant bindings include
      singleElemOnly :: [a] -> m a
        (bound at Playground.hs:12:1)
    In the expression: value
    In the expression: if (getValue isEmpty) then value else mzero
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What are the error messages?  Always post the compiler errors you see.

Comment: Sorry, the errors were quite long. I added them and fixed the example.

Comment: Add a type signature to `test1,...`: probably you want these to be of type `Maybe (Int,[Int])` or something similar. GHC picked `Integer` instead of `Int` for you. Once this type is fixed, you now can see that your function `singleElemOnly` returns only that `Int/Integer` type, while its signature promises that it works at any type `a` (and not only for `Int`). This is the type error that GHC reports.

Comment: Further, it is not clear to me what your last function should do. Can you edit your question explaining what you are trying to achieve? My guess at the moment is something like `f [] = mzero ; f (x:_) = return x` but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @chi Sorry, I updated the question with the latest code and error and a better explanation of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will translate from your specification:

> If the list contains no elements, I want to return an error.

```
f [] = mzero
```

> If the
>   list contains exactly 1 element, I want to return that element as a
>   Monad.

```
f [x] = return x
```

> If the list contains more than 1 element, I want to return an
>   error.

```
f (_:_:_) = mzero
```

So, putting everything together:

```
singleElemOnly :: (MonadPlus m) => [a] -> m a
singleElemOnly []  = mzero
singleElemOnly [x] = return x
singleElemOnly _   = mzero
       -- a _ catches everything else, no need to write the exact pattern
```

Or even more simply, since the third case includes the first:

```
singleElemOnly :: (MonadPlus m) => [a] -> m a
singleElemOnly [x] = return x
singleElemOnly _   = mzero
```

Comment: This is almost perfect! But now I need to somehow get `test1` into it as a parameter and that part still eludes me. `singleElemOnly (fmap snd test2)` does not work, it complains that it "couldn't match type `Maybe` with `[]`"?

Comment: `singleElemOnly` takes a list. `fmap snd test` has type `Maybe [Int]`. You can do `fmap (singleElement . snd) test` but this gets you a `Maybe (Maybe [Int])`. You probably want `fmap snd test >>= singleElement`.

Answer (score 1):

First, [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is your friend. You can look up signatures and find that `getFirst` is just `fst`, `getSecond` is `snd`, and your implementation of `getValue` can be written as `fromMaybe false`.

In terms of the error messages, `value` has the type `(Integral i) => Maybe i` (or something close, I don't have a compiler right now), which is one possible value that `singleElemOnly` returns. But the signature `(MonadPlus m) => [a] -> m a` says that it must return **any** `MonadPlus` that the caller wants.

Similarly, if you are running this in GHCi, then the type of `test2` defaults to `Maybe (Integer, [Integer])`, but `singleElemOnly` must be able to return **any** `Integral` type.